# Docker, R, and Shiny: 'unstable' is invalid for APT::Default-Release

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I have a Shiny app that returns a `.pdf` to a user based upon some reactive statements. The app runs as it should locally (Win10, R3.5.0). I'm trying to deploy the app to AWS with a Docker image that combines `rocker/verse` (to output `.pdf` files built from .Rmd) with Shiny.

I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/verse

MAINTAINER ME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -t unstable \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev && \
    wget --no-verbose https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb && \
    R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'rmarkdown'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')" && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'dplyr', 'googleAuthR', 'googleAnalyticsR', 'rmarkdown', 'jsonlite', 'scales', 'ggplot2', 'reshape2', 'knitr', 'Cairo'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

## Uncomment the line below to include a custom configuration file. You can download the default file at
## https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/default.config
## (The line below assumes that you have downloaded the file above to ./shiny-customized.config)
## Documentation on configuration options is available at
## http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/

COPY shiny-customized.config /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

COPY app /srv/shiny-server/

EXPOSE 3838

COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

The first `RUN` statement is taken verbatim (minus one line which copies app information) from the [`rocker/shiny` Docker file here.](https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny/blob/master/Dockerfile) My `.config` and `.sh` files are identical to those in the `rocker/shiny` github. I get the following error:

[image]

I'm quite new to Docker and Linux CLI, but not to R. What am I missing here? How can I resolve this issue?

I considered opening this as an issue on the [`rocker/shiny` github](https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny) but it's not an issue with `rocker/shiny` as when I `C: docker pull rocker/shiny` and `docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 rocker/shiny` there is no issue. It's only when I try to build a pseudo `rocker/verse`/`rocker/shiny` container image that I get the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just removing the `-t unstable` should work.

Background: `rocker/shiny` is based on `rocker/r-base` which uses a mixture of Debain testing and unstable to always have the most recent version of R available. `rocker/verse` on the other hand is based on `rocker/r-ver` which uses Debain stable as basis and compiles a specified version of R on top of that.